# Calling specific php functions using Ajax with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have done a bit of reading over the last few days as I attempt to learn about Ajax.

Most advice online seems to use jQuery, so I think this question will help anyone who wants to use vanilla JS instead.

Suppose I have a PHP file that queries the database that looks like this:

```
function1($parameter1){
// some code to query database
}

function2($parameter2){
// some code to query database
}

function3($parameter3){
// some code to query database
}
```

I want to make an Ajax call that targets a specific function for two reasons:

- other functions are irrelevant for this call
- or otherwise, I am not sure if you can get the result of more than one function from a single Ajax call?

So as far as reading tells me, to call specific functions, I need to add parameters in my XML requests, for example, $q$, $r$, $s$ and wrap each of my function in an if loop as follows:

```
if($q === 1){
  function1($parameter1){
  // some code to query database
  }
}

if($r ===1){
  function2($parameter2){
  // some code to query database
  }
}

if($s ===1){
  function3($parameter3){
  // some code to query database
  }
}
```

Then I can use something like `xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?q=1",true)` to target function 1 etc.

Is this the way to go or is there something more efficient? Efficiency in that it *seems* inefficient to have to wrap each function in an if loop to call it and something makes me think that this would have been thought of and another solution implemented.

Comment: ...Just to say I am still relatively new to this, and so my language may be imprecise and my understanding way off for which I can only apologise

Comment: There are tons of tutorials telling you exactly this. What makes you think that all of these are wrong?

Comment: You're correct and you will find ways to refine this as your understanding of code matures. You could use a `switch()` instead of an if.

Comment: I haven't really come across one that is directly instructive and so I have put this together from trying to reverse engineer the jQuery codes I have seen. I was just thinking that there may be another more 'efficient' way to target specific functions given how many methods exist to save the very basic keystrokes